# 9patch doesnt work properly in android

Tags: android, android-layout, nine-patch

I am trying to add a 9 patch drawing to my application. In my application's image there are 2 things I have to consider. One is middle circle and other thing is two decarations at header and footer of the image. without disterbing these I have to stetch the image. According to 9patch I marked streching area but it doesnt work as I expect.

And I noticed that when I press ctr key and press black square it changes in to red color. what does it mean?

Herewith I attach the image to get the idea. [image: 9patch image]

I think you can notice left right border of the image. there, I have make black where it should be stretch. but it doesn't as I expects.
Another problem is there was a white boarder around the image in previous 9patch image.

can anybody tell where I have done the mistake?

Here is the out put[image]

Comment: This image is not designed to be easily stretchable. And don't use the red pixels.

Comment: why do you say that this image is not designed to be easily stretched.

Answer (score 1):

1. the red pixels is still a new feature that won't work yet.
2. did you save it as png or jpg (must be png) ? did you also remember to change the name of the file to have ".9" before the extension ?
3. try to use the 9-patch tool that is included in the sdk . it will also show you a preview of what it will look like when stretched .
4. there are plenty of tutorials of how to handle 9-patch images . for the left and top parts , you select which parts to stretch , and for the right and bottom parts , you select where to put the content (for example text in the case of a button) .

Comment: for 1. ok 2. save correct format 3. yes I did 4. I did only for the left part not for the right handside part.

Comment: and there is a white boarder around my 9 patch.

Comment: it's not a white border , it should be a transparent border . it should be for all sides , even if you don't use the right and bottom sides. the tool is supposed to add the border by itself automatically .

Comment: can you please show what is the expected behavior and the one you are seeing ? currently what you've shown is only the input file . i need to know what could be wrong here . maybe even show the layout xml file that shows the image?

Comment: did you try to un-mark the areas that you didn't want to stretch ? according to the picture , you've marked it in red . also , it seems you didn't mark the horizontal stretching .

Comment: horizontaly I dont want to stretch , if I do then circle becomes elipse. And how to set not to strech in a 9patch?

Comment: if you won't allow stretching horizontally , you will get empty spaces for some devices that do not match the aspect ratio of your image. about not stretching areas , just remove the pixels you've marked in the 9-patch tool using the right click of the mouse . only the black pixels are those that will stretch the image.

Comment: I think my picture is high quality it is near 700kb ~1 mb therrefore , image doesnt need to stetch. it is fit for even xhdp without stretching

Comment: makes sense . maybe i should have asked for the original image and think about this myself. write down the answer and tick it so that everybody else will know about it. 9-patch images are usually very small .

Comment: another important thing I need to know is that should create 9patch image as a transparent image?

Comment: depends on what you want to achieve . if you need some transparent areas , put transparent pixels. in any case , it must be of a png format .

Answer (score 0):

I just thought to share my knowledge after working several days on this. 9patch images are actually good for buttons  small icons , small labels and etc. They are good for background layouts when Background images are not consist of lot of colors and designs. In above problem it is hard to get a good look when image is stretch with 9patch technique.

My solution is using different layout files for this case.This techniques is used for large display such as tablets when we have to change the designing that is done for mobiles.
Here is how file structure should be arranged.

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation
```

Anybody interested about this can get more information from this 
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html